# How to Insert records from another object in section with visualforce

Tags: visualforce, related-list

I need to insert a section on my visualforce page displaying list of records from another object. I have an object called `VM_Sales_Order__c` on which `Shipping_Address__c` is a lookup field. On `VM_Sales_Order__c` I have an vf page called VMSalesOrderUserEditpage which is taken to by clicking Edit button on the `VM_Sales_Order__c`.

`Shipping_Address__c` object has an related list of `VM_Sales_Order__c` records. I want to show `VM_Sales_Order__c` records list on my vf page "VMSalesOrderUserEditpage".

I tried to display these record using `<apex:relatedList>` it gives me an error message

> List attribute parent name 'Shipping_Address__r' is an invalid field name for entity VM Sales Order"

Can someone suggest me what is the best way to achieve this.

Below is my vf page

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="VM_Sales_Order__c">
```

Lab Id Assignment Page

```
        <!-- **********   [Record Type : Master ]   **********  -->
        <apex:outputpanel >
            <apex:pageblocksection title="Information" showheader="true" columns="2">
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Name}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Order_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Customer_Account__c}"/>                 
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Database_Origin__c}"/>
                <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
            </apex:pageblocksection>
            <apex:pageblocksection title="PO Contact Information" showheader="true" columns="2">
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Contact_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Customer_PO__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Contact_Phone__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Principle_Investigator__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Quote_No__c}"/>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
            <apex:pageblocksection title="Address" showheader="true" columns="2">
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Ship_To_Address_Line_1__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Sold_To_Address_Line_1__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Ship_To_Address_Line_2__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Sold_To_Address_Line_2__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Ship_To_Address_Line_3__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Sold_To_Address_Line_3__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Ship_To_City__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Sold_To_City__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Ship_To_Company_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Sold_To_Company_Name__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Ship_To_Country__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Sold_To_Country__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Ship_To_Postal_Code__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Sold_To_Postal_Code__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Ship_To_State_Province__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Sold_To_State_Province__c}"/>
                <apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.SoldinTerritory__c}"/>
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:pageblock>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Shipping Address with realted VM Sales Orders">
<apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Shipping_Address__c}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Shipping_Address__r.Name}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>

<apex:relatedList list="Shipping_Address__r.name"/>   
<center><br/>
    <i style="font-size:30px;color:#aaa;">Lab Id Assignment Page </i>
</center><br/>
```

Comment: It seems to me that you need to think your requirements out some more. `<apex:relatedList>` is the way to go, but trying to display the `VM_Sales_Order__c` related list from your `Shipping_Address__c` record on a page that operates on a `VM_Sales_Order__c` record doesn't make much sense to me (at least with your current description).

Comment: Also, "it didn't work" isn't a very useful statement. If you're getting an error message, please include it **verbatim**. If you're not getting an error, explaining what you're seeing, and how it's different from what you _expect_ to see, is helpful. Including your visualforce page is also recommended. You can do all of this if you [edit] your question.

Comment: Can you share your VF page and controller?

Comment: Hi Derek, I know it doesn't make sense to get  VM_Sales_Order__c records list from Shipping_Address__c but that's exactly my current requirement. I would like to display all the  VM_Sales_Order__c  records that are related to the Shipping_Address__c record on our  VM_Sales_Order__c page look up. Also I have updated the error message in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not quite sure why you want to display a list of `VM_Sales_Order__c` records on a page where you're editing a `VM_Sales_Order__c` record, but seeing your visualforce, it's easy to see where you're going wrong here.

The [documentation on apex:relatedList](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm) will be helpful.

From that page, the `list` attribute is meant to contain the name of the related list that you want to display (not the name of the individual record, as you currently have). That means that you want to be using the *child relationship name*, which is generally the plural of the child object name (unless you explicitly set it to something else when you created the lookup field to `Shipping_Address__c`).

Also from that page, the `subject` attribute defaults to the Id of the record that the visualforce page is operating on. You'll need to override the default to display a related list on another object.

All together, your related list tag should look like this

```html
<!-- "VM Sales Orders" is just my best guess at what you'll actually need to use -->
<!-- The subject attribute needs an Id, and lookup fields store an Id (even though
  salesforce turns this into the name of the related record when viewed through 
  a page layout or visualforce page) -->
<apex:relatedList list="VM Sales Orders" subject="{!VM_Sales_Order__c.Shipping_Address__c}" />
```

Comment: I am getting an error saying 'VM Sales Orders' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Shipping Address after modifying the related list.

Comment: @Ram Like I said, that was only my best guess. If that wasn't it, then you'll need to go to the object definition for `VM_Sales_Order__c`, dig into the `Shipping_Address__c` lookup field, and look for the "Child Relationship Name" field.